# Problem understanding 1 step in integration

Tags: calculus

I am reading some book which require the following simplification, but  I don't understand how did we get to the second step below

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} 
\frac{\partial \dot{y}}{\partial \alpha}dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial{x}\partial \alpha}dx$$

How did we get that second equality ?

Comment: I think it's just by substituting $\dot{y} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ is a function with multiple variables, we have
$$\dot{y}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$
Therefore
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} 
\frac{\partial \dot{y}}{\partial \alpha}dx$$
$$=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot y} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right) dx$$
$$=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot y} 
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \alpha\partial x} dx$$
$$=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot y} 
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x\partial \alpha} dx$$
Usually [Newton's notation for differentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton.27s_notation) is used to denote derivatives with respect to time.